# Modified \overline over first character of complex argument

Tags: math-mode, cross-referencing, expansion, zref

I've been using [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref) to handle my references. It has allowed me to customize a reference the way I want through its property lists. In particular, I reference a variety of structures in my document that are created in an automated way. Here's a MWE that provides the setup and illustrates my current problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/zref
\makeatletter
\newcounter{thegraph}% Graph counter
\zref@newlist{graph}% Graph reference stored in list 'graph'
\zref@newprop*{type}[??]{??}% Create new 'graph type' property
\zref@newprop*{number}[??]{\thethegraph}% Create new 'graph number' property
\zref@addprops{graph}{type, number}% Graph reference (or property list) has type & number
\newcommand{\graph}[1]{\zref@setcurrent{type}{G}\newgraph{1}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\digraph}[1]{\zref@setcurrent{type}{D}\newgraph{2}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\newgraph}[2]{% New graph #1=type; #2=ref
  \refstepcounter{thegraph}% Increase counter
  % zref label has to written immediately (not at page shipout), since more than one new graph may appear on page
  \zref@wrapper@immediate{\zref@labelbylist{#2}{graph}}% Write graph list to .aux (using zref)
  \label{#2}% Label newgraph for reference
  \ifnum#1>0\ensuremath{\zref@getcurrent{type}_{\thethegraph}}\fi% Print graph symbol (if requested)
}
\newcommand{\graphref}[1]{\ensuremath{\zref@extract{#1}{type}_{\zref@extract{#1}{number}}}}% Reference to a graph
\newcommand{\complementg@aux}[2][3]{{}\mkern#1mu\overline{\mkern-#1mu#2}}
\newcommand{\complementg}[2][3]{\edef\@tempa{#2}\expandafter\complementg@aux\expandafter[\expandafter#1\expandafter]\@tempa}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is~\graph{first} and~\digraph{second}. Now see~\graphref{first} and~\graphref{second}.
What about~$\complementg{\graphref{first}}$ and~$\complementg{\graphref{second}}$?

\end{document}
```

The above MWE gives the following output

[image]

while I'd like it to look like this:

[image]

```
This is~$G_1$ and~$D_2$. Now see~$G_1$ and~$D_2$.
What about~$\complementg{G_1}$ and~$\complementg{D_2}$?
```

The choice of `\complementg` stems from [a discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7493887#7493887) and because it worked in a non-`zref` implementation.

My question is: How can I define `\complementg` such that allows for being used in all of the following formats while only providing a "modified `\overline`" for the first character:

```
$\complementg{G_1}$% Basic math content with subscript manual subscript
$\complementg{\graphref{lab}}$% Referenced zref label (like above)
$\complementg{\mathcal{G}}$% "Complex" formatting of content
```

---

In a typographic sense, this question is somewhat related to [What's the proper way to write a vector with a single character subscript?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44799/5764)

Comment: Just remove `\ensuremath` from the definition of `\graphref`. Have I already said that `\ensuremath` is to be used carefully? ;-)

Comment: "complex", "argument", "graph" - all are ambiguous terms (often associated with complex analysis). Then I discovered the word `\digraph`. Hence, this is about graph theory and compound TeX arguments. (+1) Interesting approach!

Comment: Did you see [this answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another pearl for my don't-use-`\ensuremath`-unless-really-necessary campaign.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{thegraph}% Graph counter
\zref@newlist{graph}% Graph reference stored in list 'graph'
\zref@newprop*{type}[??]{??}% Create new 'graph type' property
\zref@newprop*{number}[??]{\thethegraph}% Create new 'graph number' property
\zref@addprops{graph}{type, number}% Graph reference (or property list) has type & number

\newcommand{\graph}[1]{\zref@setcurrent{type}{G}\newgraph{1}{#1}}%

\newcommand{\digraph}[1]{\zref@setcurrent{type}{D}\newgraph{2}{#1}}%

\newcommand{\newgraph}[2]{% New graph #1=type; #2=ref
  \refstepcounter{thegraph}% Increase counter
  % zref label has to written immediately (not at page shipout),
  % since more than one new graph may appear on page
  \zref@wrapper@immediate{\zref@labelbylist{#2}{graph}}% Write graph list to .aux (using zref)
  \label{#2}% Label newgraph for reference
  % Print graph symbol (if requested)
  \ifnum#1>\z@\ensuremath{\zref@getcurrent{type}_{\thethegraph}}\fi
}
%%% DON'T use \ensuremath here
\newcommand{\graphref}[1]{\zref@extract{#1}{type}_{\zref@extract{#1}{number}}}% Reference to a graph
\newcommand{\complementg@aux}[2][3]{{}\mkern#1mu\overline{\mkern-#1mu#2}}

%%% Less clumsy definition of \complementg    
\newcommand{\complementg}[2][3]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
  \unexpanded{\complementg@aux[#1]}#2}\x}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is~\graph{first} and~\digraph{second}. 
Now see~$\graphref{first}$ and~$\graphref{second}$.
What about~$\complementg{\graphref{first}}$ 
and~$\complementg{\graphref{second}}$?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this is *the* pearl for me, since I've never seen it to be the problem you perpetually purport. `:)` The reason for using it stems from a document I've been working on for years... as such, since the problem didn't creep up until recently, I didn't give it much attention. Thanks...