# Proper way to typset minimum value of variable in formula?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, typography, math-operators

To typeset a value with a subscript I use this:

```
$U_{\text{res}}$
```

Which results in:

[image: Ures]

Now I'd like to write "the minimum value of Ures", how would I correctly typeset that?

The first thing I tried was

```
$U_{\text{res}_{\text{min}}}$
```

[image: Uresmin]

but that doesn't really look good. A coworker suggested

```
$U_{\text{res,min}}}$
```

[image: Ures,min]

but I'm also not sure if it's correct, and as part of a larger formula it seems to take up too much horizontal space:

[image: formula]

Comment: Not really your question but it's better to use \mathrm than \text it's far more efficient and uses a fixed font, whereas text will pick up the current text font so would be italc in italic theorem texts

Comment: I would highly recommend you use the letters "max" for **maximum** and reserve "min" for minimum. :-). An alternative to a subscript would be a function: $\mathrm{Max} (U_{res})$

Comment: Or, stick to the good old inequalities: say, `$U_{\mathrm{trig}} \geqslant blahbah$`. And, in the first of the equalities you display, you might consider using \left(\right) around the first term of the product, so that, the braces expand according the size of what goes inside them.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Interesting objection.  Aside from efficiency, all the reasons you give are always advanced as arguments *for* `\text` (though admittedly, in contrast with `\mbox`).

Comment: I would propose a definition of minimum/maximum being something like `\underline{U}_{\mathrm{res}}`/`\overline{U}_{\mathrm{res}}`, and perhaps incorporating some shift in the `\overline` (see [Modified `\overline` over first character of complex argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109704/5764) and/or [Can I get a `\widebar` without using the `mathabx` package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16337/5764)).

Comment: @RyanReich if you are making a side condition or have some other _text_ then `\text` is fine but here `max` is not a word it is essentially a math operator and should come from the math operator font to match `\log` or `\sin` etc and that will be the math roman font and not change depending on the outer text content.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a unique proper way of doing this.

There is the operator $\min$ which might be appropriate here.

In order to define your own operators, consider using `\DeclareMathOperator{\Minimum}{Minimum}` from amsmath to be able to use `$\Minimum U_\mathrm{res}$`. Using the operator will give you suitable spacing around the operator, just as you have with i.e. `\sin`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Why not just use `\min`

Comment: Aditya, I somehow missed that. I corrected my answer accordingly. At least I it becomes clear to me again why I couldn't find a `\min` in my own math convenience package :)