# Using resizebox on sub-expressions in math mode

Tags: math-mode

As part of an image that I am generating I need the ability to shrink or grow part of a math expression by a numerically controlled/arbitrary amount. Can anyone think of a way to do this?
For example I would like to shrink or grow the radical and everything in it, but leave the rest of the standard quadratic formula standard size.

Comment: See the `scalerel` package as a possibility

Answer (score 1):

You might have some luck using the `\scalebox` command in the `graphicx` package. In the example below, I have defined a `\grow{n}{...}` command that scales the given expression by a factor `n`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\grow[2]{\ensuremath{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}}
\begin{document}
\[
x = \frac{-b \pm \grow{3}{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}}{2a}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is no need for `\ensuremath` here.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: It should be `x_{1,2}=...` ;-)

Comment: @Werner Hm. But I'd need `\ensuremath` if I'd used a `raisebox` or `makebox`, no?

Comment: @JohnWickerson: It depends. [Some people](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) are strictly opposed to `\ensuremath`. I've had [my own problems with it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109704/5764) and therefore base most of my decisions on whether it is really necessary. I mean, what's a couple of `$`s between friends? ;) `\scalebox`, `\raisebox` and `\makebox` internally switch to text mode via `\hbox` and text inside math is fine. It's about trying to [maintain the current math style which is difficult](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78872/5764). Consider `\sum_{i=1}` in your case.